# Function over matrices, continuous and differentiable?

Tags: matrices

How can I prove that a function which takes an nxn matrix and returns that matrix cubed, is a continuous function?
Also, how can I analyze if the function is differenciable or not?

About the continuity I took a generic matrix A and considered the matrix A + h, where h is a real tending to zero. Then I generalized the product of two matrices A and B where the result is a matrix with a sum in each entry. Then the result of the product of the matrices A+h and B+h is a matrix like A.B plus some constants tending to zero.
Although I'm not sure that's enough to prove the continuity.

Any help with this and the differenciation?

Thanks!

Comment: As said in the answer, $h$ needs to be a matrix too, and then $$(A+H)^3=A^3+A^2H+AHA+HA^2+AH^2+HAH+H^2A+H^3.$$ Using a multiplicative matrix norm, $\|(A+H)^3-A^3\|$ can be estimated against $\|H\|$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "the matrix $A+h$, where $h$ is a real tending to zero" makes no sense. $A$ is a matrix, but $h$ is a real number, and you can't add matrices and real numbers.

In any case, the slickest thing to do is this: just think of your function as a map $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\to\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ by identifying an $n\times n$ matrix with an $n^2$-dimensional vector. The components of your function are going to be *polynomials* in the $n^2$ variables, so your map will be both differentiable and continuous.